# Run function on video element(among other videos) that just exited fullscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 8 videos on a page. on each video element i have add some things like sound control and description. 
Specifically, the sound control mutes and umutes the video on click and also changes its icon accordingly. Hoever, when the video goes full screen, the browser uses its own controls for sound. So, for example  if a user watches a video on mute, then goes full screen, and then turns on sound, and then exits full screen, the sound is still on but the sound control suggests it is not.
So i'd like to run a function every time any video on the page exits full screen, to update the sound icon.

Here's my html for the video element. I have 8 identical video elements on the page:

```
<div class="section-element video-mockup" onmouseenter="hoverIn($(this))" onmouseleave="hoverOut($(this))">
    <video loop muted playsinline preload="metadata" class="video-onhover" controlsList="nodownload" onclick="clickPlay($(this))" ondblclick="toggleFullscreen(this)">
        <source src="/wp-content/uploads/wysiwyg/webm/Video.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="/wp-content/uploads/wysiwyg/webm/Video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div class="section-inner video-overlay">
        <hr class="whiteLine">
        <div class="videoControls">
            <div class="overlay-columns description">
                <p class="overlay-text"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="overlay-columns buttons">
                <button class="videoButtons sound-button" title="Sound" onclick="toggleSound(this);"><ion-icon name="volume-off"></ion-icon></button>
                <button class="videoButtons reset-button" title="Restart" onclick="expandVideo(this);"><ion-icon name="expand"></ion-icon></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I am trying to update the `<button class="videoButtons sound-button" title="Sound" onclick="toggleSound(this);">` on any video that exits fullscreen.
Here's my code for that:

```
$('video.video-onhover').on('fullscreenchange', function($this) {
    var thisVideo = $this.target;
    console.log(thisVideo);
    var soundButton = thisVideo.parentElement.querySelector('button.sound-button');
    if (thisVideo.muted) {
        soundButton.innerHTML = '<ion-icon name="volume-off"></ion-icon>';
    } else {
        soundButton.innerHTML = '<ion-icon name="volume-high"></ion-icon>';
    }
});
```

I added the `console.log` to see if the function is being called, but it doesn't seem to run. i am guessing there is something wrong with the `fullscreenchange` event but i can't find any other way. Any ideas?

Comment: Reading the docs on fullscreenchange it sounds like that you need to add the event listener to the document rather than an element? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fullscreenchange_event

Comment: But I need to find out which video just exited fullscreen, so i can't use it on the document, right?

Comment: Sorry it also says "Another fullscreenchange event will be sent to the Element which is itself transitioning into or out of full-screen mode." So it sounds like your code should be ok?

Comment: try the example listed on this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fullscreenchange_event